# qml: DelegateModel + Package makes delegate have null parent transiently

Tags: qt, qml

When using using **Package**, **State** and **ParentChange** to re-parent a delegate to one of several views, the delegate seems to momentarily have a null parent while bindings are re-evaluated.  This causes errors if the delegate has bindings to *parent*.width or similar.

This is disturbing because Qt's published ***Package*** example displays the same problem if the initial state is changed to the other alternative

(To reproduce: copy ..../Qt/Examples/Qt-5.14.1/quick/views/package/{view.qml,Delegate.qml} and change the initial `upTo` value from 0 to 7 in view.qml and then run "qmlscene view.qml".).

Below is a simplification of Qt's example, with a constant *state*.  The active **State** uses a **ParentChange** which defines *width*; this somehow causes the delegate to momentarily have a null parent, and the binding for width:parent.width gets an error:

> test.qml line 26: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

What causes this, or rather, how to avoid it? And, how could the Package mechanism ever work given that Qt's example has the same problem as noted above?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 300; height: 400

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
        ListElement { display: "One" }
        ListElement { display: "Two" }
        ListElement { display: "Three" }
    }
    DelegateModel {
        id: visualModel
        model: myModel
        delegate:
          Package {
            Rectangle { id: rectA;
              width: 40; height: 25; Package.name: 'pkgA'
            }
            Rectangle { id: rectB;
              width: 40; height: 25; Package.name: 'pkgB'
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: wrapper
                width: parent.width; // ERROR HERE: parent is sometimes null!
                height: 25
                color: 'lightsteelblue'
                state: 'state1'
                states: [
                    State {
                        name: 'state1'
                        ParentChange {
                            target: wrapper; parent: rectB
                            width: rectB.width; height: rectB.height // **CAUSES ERROR**
                        }
                    }
                ]
                Component.onCompleted: {
                  console.log("wrapper onCompleted: parent is",parent);
                }
                onParentChanged: {
                  console.log("wrapper parent changed to",parent);
                }
            }
          }
    }
    ListView {
        width: 300; height: 200
        model: visualModel.parts.pkgA
    }
    ListView {
        width: 300; height: 200
        model: visualModel.parts.pkgB
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you are seeing is a transient condition during the creation of the components from the Package delegate definition before the reparenting occurs. Which means it indeed would be a bug in the example also without a guard against `parent == null`. It may help to put an `onParentChanged` handler on it and have it log out the various values of parent as it changes.

Comment: I tried using `onParentChanged`, and parent is never null!   However it is null sometimes when the binding `width: parent.width` is evaluated, so this transient condition seems illegitimate, i.e. it is set to null in a way which does not trigger onParentChanged.   If you replace that binding with `width: { console.log("parent is",parent); return parent.width; }` then it prints "parent is null" (and then crashes).

Comment: Ok, so that tells me parent is starting as null (as onParentChanged won't fire for the initial value). You might see this if you log it on Component.onCompleted.

Comment: Nope.  You should try it yourself.   I updated the example to log  parent at onParentChanged and Component.onCompleted.  The output never shows a null value

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally figured this out. You are starting with this:

```
width: parent.width
```

which is a Qt binding expression. It will update whenever `parent` or `parent.width` changes. And when the `wrapper` Rectangle first is created, `parent` starts rightly as `null` - it has no visual parent yet.

But then you do a ParentChange like this:

```
    ParentChange {
        target: wrapper; parent: rectB
        width: rectB.width; height: rectB.height // **CAUSES ERROR**
    }
```

The `width` assignment in the `ParentChange` is removing your previous binding and placing a new one of `rectB.width` width on it. This is why console logging on the original binding stops firing at this point. That binding has been removed.

So, bottom line, you are misinterpreting what is happening. Parent is `null` *to start with* and gets set via the `state` initial value before `Component.onCompleted` fires. Then when you do the `ParentChange`, you are wiping out the original binding so the debugging you went through was misleading.

So back to your original question, to stop the error, just remove the `width` and `height` bindings altogether from `wrapper` and let the `ParentChange` apply the ones there which won't throw errors.

Comment: >>> I'm still not seeing how, then, Qt's unmodified example (referenced in original post) does not have the same problem.  It has `width:parent.width`

Comment: If parent was always normally `null` when the *wrapper* Rectangle in my simplified example is first instantiated, then it's `width:parent.width` would always cause an error.  But it does not...   if the ParentChange does not try to specify width then no error occurs (e.g. if the `width: rectB.width` in the ParentChange is commented out)

Comment: I'm not sure why their example is behaving differently. Could be a slightly different sequence of steps due to how you are handling `states` than the example is.